# Send canvas and form to server save image with custom name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to send the canvas image to the server.

Hi everyone I know this has been asked a lot. (I've already asked it once before)

The form data is sent too and this is used to name the file sent to the server so that it is identifiable who drew the image.

My site is [here](http://www.lovetriangles.co.uk/indexPHPtest.html)!

HTML

```
 <form action="PHPtestupload.php" method="post">
      Name <input type="text" name="name" value="" style="width:230px;  margin-left: -160px; font-size:1em; "/>

      Email <input type="email" name="email" value="" style="width:230px;  margin-top: 12px; margin-left: -160px; font-size:1em; "/>


      <input type="submit" onclick="postImagePlusForm();" value="Submit" style=" opacity:1; -webkit-appearance: none; width:100px; height:50px; margin-left: -50px;">
    </form>
```

JS

```
      // sends image to server
// serialize your canvas
var dataURL=document.getElementById('colors_sketch').toDataURL(image/png);

// serialize your form
var str = $("form").serializeArray();

// wrap both in an object
var package={ formData: str, imageDataURL: dataURL }




// ajax it
postImagePlusForm();

function postImagePlusForm(){
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "PHPtestupload.php",  
    data: package,  
    success: function(value) {  
        // ...we have success!
    }
});
```

}

PHP

```
if ( isset($_POST["imageDataURL"]) && !empty($_POST["imageDataURL"]) ) {    
 // create $dataURL
$dataURL = $_POST["imageDataURL"];  
// Extract base64 data
// we have an unneeded header, zap it
$parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
$data = $parts[1];  
// Decode
$data = base64_decode($data);  
// Save
$fp = fopen('newImage.png', 'w');  
fwrite($fp, $data);  
fclose($fp); 

if ( isset($_POST["formData"]) && !empty($_POST["formData"]) ) {    
$formData = $_POST['formData'];
foreach ($formValue as $x) {
    // do whatever you need to do with each form value ($x)

}
```

Alternative PHP using different Javascript on the web page, with semi-working site [here](http://www.lovetriangles.co.uk/index1.html)!

I think that the server shuts down the PHP as it functions locally but doesn't work when online. It generates lots of error logs.

```
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

        $canvasImg = imagecreatefrompng($data);
        $width  = imagesx($canvasImg);
        $height = imagesy($canvasImg);


        $outImg = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($outImg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefill($outImg, 0, 0, $color);
        imagecopy($outImg, $canvasImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);


        imagepng($outImg, 'test.png');


        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $target = 'test.png';
        $newName = $name . $email;
        rename($target, $newName);
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work. No image created! Have a look at my site for the full code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dataURL = $_POST["imageDataURL"];
$dataURL = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $dataURL);
$dataURL = str_replace(' ', '+', $dataURL);
$image = base64_decode($dataURL);
$filename = 'newImage.png';
file_put_contents('path/to/' . $filename, $image);
```

Also, in your Javascript you missed out the quotations in `.toDataURL`

```
var dataURL = document.getElementById('colors_sketch').toDataURL('image/png');
```

**--- UPDATE ---**

In your case, the image data is actually not being passed to your upload handler (PHPtestuplaod.php) since submitting the form will cause a page redirect. So a possible workaround on this will be:

**HTML**

```
<!-- add this inside your form. 
     this will be used to carry the image data into
     the upload handler -->
<input type="hidden" name="imageData" id="imageData" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  // let's prevent the default behavior for now,
  // so that we'll have time to include the image data
  e.preventDefault();

  // get the canvas image data
  var imageData = document.getElementById("colors_sketch").toDataURL("image/png");

  // let the hidden field we added earlier carry the image data into the upload handler
  $("#imageData").val(imageData);

  // submit the form
  $(this).submit();
});
```

**PHP**

```
$dataURL = $_POST["imageData"];
$dataURL = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $dataURL);
$dataURL = str_replace(' ', '+', $dataURL);
$image = base64_decode($dataURL);
$filename = 'newImage.png';
file_put_contents('path/to/' . $filename, $image);
```

You may want to remove your AJAX call, since it won't be needed here now.

Comment: Thanks. It is writing but it is a blank image.

Comment: I had assumed so. Check my website on the link above. It is the id of the canvas.
I had this working with the code in this [link](http://www.lovetriangles.co.uk/index1.html)!
This has different PHP but I am getting error codes and I think the server ends up stopping it from working.

Comment: I have posted the PHP it uses above

Comment: Can you try printing out the `$dataURL`. It should be something like this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAJECAYAAADKclo8AAAgAElEQVR4Xu3dgW0jiXWA4XMFTgdWB44r8LoCJxVYqSBOBblUEKeCrCuIU4HXFcRXQZQOkg4y70wagiBKJPVLwxl9BIhd7FKPw28ecD+GXN5PvnMjQIAAAQIE[etc etc..too long]`

Comment: and placing it in the dataURL = $_POST["data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA..."]

Comment: Hi where is it this is being placed?

Comment: Place the PHP code in your PHPtestupload.php or whichever file handles the file upload. As for the blank image, I'm still trying to figure out why is it like that. I'm suspecting that the image data is not passed properly into your PHP.

Comment: And keep the `$dataURL` as it is: `dataURL = $_POST["imageDataURL"];`

Comment: That is what I did, replace my existing PHP with the original one you suggested. What else is going wrong?

Comment: Ah, I get it now. It's because you're passing the data to the `PHPtestupload.php` file through the form, not through AJAX. With the form getting submitted, your AJAX call actually doesn't execute (maybe it executes but it doesn't get finished), leaving behind the image data.

Comment: I'll update my answer to include a possible workaround on this.

Comment: Thanks Arnelle.

Cool site btw I really like the tracking for the dots behind. Very nice touch!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Did it work already? Sorry it took me a while to figure it out. And thanks also :)

Comment: No this isn't working unfortunately.
Oh and don't worry, I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Still getting the blank image?

Comment: Well with the amendments it isn't submitting to the PHP page

Comment: Oh, so passing it using the hidden input field isn't helping. But I'm confident that the problem is the one which I've stated previously. We just need to find the right way to do it.

Comment: Any ideas, I'm very new to sending things over to PHP so quite in the dark.

Comment: What I did in my site is that I submitted everything with AJAX, which means I didn't have a form in my HTML markup. This helps me avoid the unwanted page redirect when submitting the form.

Comment: But if you want to keep your form, I'm still thinking of a way to do it. The one I suggested earlier failed, so I'm looking for something else.

Comment: Yeah I would like the form to exist within the page. What alternative structure would I use to do it your way?

Comment: Have you got your PHP you can share. A way I can amend my code to match something along the lines of yours by having the form appear seperately?

Comment: Sure, I can send my whole source code for the site if you want. Just tell me where to send it.

Comment: I can't really tell you which ones to add because I don't know the whole structure of what you're building. I can only answer the ones relevant to the problem you posted (am I making sense?)

Comment: This guy spent this amount of support on this, and didn't even get an upvote?

Comment: @NateFlink at the time I wasn't ranked enough to do so. Fixed :)